# How to insert an action in a menu with Qt Designer?

Tags: qt, qt-designer, qaction

It is convenient to add actions to a menu with QtDesigner by typing some texts in the "Type Here" box. However, the "Type Here" box is always at the below. How to insert an action at a particular position, for example, under or above the existing action "Open"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just insert as you already do, then drag and drop it to the desired position.

Comment: You can also move them with Ctrl+Up and Ctrl+Down.